# How to transit to resource manager from service management?

Tags: azure

I have an asmx webservice that is hosted in azure cloud and it has been active for the past 2 years and recently I have received an email from Microsoft stating that

> "Azure App Service resource management will now be supported only
>   through   Azure Resource Manager. Support through Azure Service
>   Management will be   retired on June 30, 2018. Transition to Resource
>   Manager to keep   programmatically managing your resources."
>
> Dear Azure customer, You’re receiving this email because you’re a
>   current Azure App Service  customer, and you use an Azure Service
>   Management–based client to  programmatically manage your App Service
>   resources.
>
> The Resource Manager portal and APIs have replaced the legacy Service 
>   Management portal and APIs for managing App Service resources.
>   Beginning  June 30, 2018, App Service resources will be supported only
>   by Resource  Manager. You’ll no longer be able to manage App Service
>   resources using  Service Management.
>
> Resource Manager offers a number of advantages over legacy Service 
>   Management, including: •  A robust resource deployment model. 
>   • Built-in role-based access control.  •  Fully supported REST API and
>   clients for existing and new features.
>
> Recommended action
>
> We recommend you transition any automation that programmatically
>   manages App  Service resources using Service Management APIs to
>   Resource Manager APIs by  June 30, 2018. The specific steps you’ll
>   take depend on what client(s) your automation is  coded against. Read
>   our blog post to learn more about the transition and any  action you
>   might need to take.

I am not sure whether this is a kind of question to be posted here but i thought someone familiar with azure will be able to shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure App Services were removed from the "old" portal, https://manage.windowsazure.com and can only anymore be accessed from the "new" portal, https://portal.azure.com.

If you got some web app created using the old portal, then you need to managed it using the new portal.

The above email is regarding any customization that rely on the old portal, and its APIs to function. You need to update them to use the new portal, and its API for them to continue functioning after June 30, 2018.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do i also have to migrate my asmx webservice into WebAPI?

Comment: No need for that, the app service itself is not going anywhere and will continue functioning as such. If it's working at the moment, then no need to touch the logic.

Comment: Great! Thanks again.